# Url rewrite querstring getting appended after postback event in iis 7

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module, postbackurl

i have a problem with URL rewrite module with iis 7.5.

I have made friendly urls which formats the querstrings in the friendly url formats like

> http:domain.com/Blog/Category-2/Welcome-to-your-Blog

Everything is working fine. but on asp.net postback event its again appending the querystrinng as mentioned below

> http://domain.com/Blog/Category-2/Welcome-to-your-Blog?Category=Category-2&post=Welcome-to-your-Blog!

but i don't want this to happen in url. 
please help how i can avoid this. from appending the querstrings.

Comment: Can you post your rewrite rule(s)?